# Show abbreviations completely in some parts of the text

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I am writing my thesis and am using abbreviations.
I have a tex file where I list all my abbreviations:

```
\chapter*{Abbreviations}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abbreviations}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{UI}{User Interface}
\acro{IoT}{Internet of Things}
\end{acronym}
```

In the tex file where I have the documentation, I am using the `\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}` and I refer to my abbreviation like this `\acr{IoT}`. 
The first one is shown like this **Internet of Things (IoT)** and then the others like this **IoT**. How can I make the abbreviation show completely in some parts of text except the first time that I am using the abbreviation? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I found `\acf` which does that job.

Example:

```
\ac{IoT} is \acf{IoT}
```

will show **IoT is Internet of Things(IoT)**